# window.matchMedia does not work in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, mobile-safari

Why does the following code not work in Safari?

```
window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener('change', () => {
 console.log('theme changed');
});
```

Comment: sorry simply not supported

Comment: @ronrupp hey, if my answer provided some help and/or insight, please consider marking it as accepted :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted [here on caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=matchMedia) and [here on mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList#Browser_compatibility), `MediaQueryList.addEventListener` doesn't work in Safari and IE, however you can use `MediaQueryList.addListener`:

> Older browsers should use addListener instead of addEventListener since MediaQueryList only inherits from EventTarget in newer browsers. [[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener)]